# Show second spinner dialog once first spinner has selected an item, if not then show message

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a form where I have a spinner for state and a spinner for city. I already populate the city spinner when a state has been selected. The issue is to show an error message saying something like "Please choose a state first", when the user tries to choose a city without having chosen a state, without triggering the onitemselected listener. I thought maybe adding/removing the listener depending on whether a state is currently chosen but then how to trigger the error message? any thoughts? thank you.

ps: I tried working with setEnabled and setClickable false but that did not work.

Comment: Enable the city spinner if the state is selected, disable it otherwise

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi but then how can I show a message when the city spinner is clicked?

Comment: set the first element of the state spinner with a "select country" value. Use OnItemSelectedListener on the state spinner to trigger the user action, if pos index of onItemSelected callback is >0 enable the city spinner, otherwise disable it . You don't need to show a message

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi "well duh!" is how it feels to not have thought of that, thank you very much. I up voted your comment, not really sure how to have that be the accepted answer, tho.

Comment: Don't worry let me do this